# dialog box with multiple checkboxes android souce code

Tags: java, android

I have an android app with a button. When clicking the button I need on the screen a dialob box with multiple check boxes annd an ok button. How to do that? Do i need an xml layout for the list with checkboxes?

**1. How to add to each element in the list dialog box a check box?**

**2. How to put in a string all the checked elements when the button OK is pressed.**

this is my code so far:

```
 app_part.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String items[] = {"1","2","3","4"};

                AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(ConferenceClass.this);
                ab.setTitle("SIP CONTACTS");
                ab.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
                    // on OK button action
                    }
                    });
                ab.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
                    // on Cancel button action
                    }
                    });
                ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {


                }
                });
                ab.show();
                 //open contact list and select persons


                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes u can just create the layout like you would normally do, when u design a activity layout. THe only different is that you have to set in your manifest that its a dialog.

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"